# Is there any way to set multiplication margin in css?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, calc

I have a container an I need to put a box in the middle, but I cant get a static height to parent because its going to change. because of that my box cant be set in the middle of the page. I need some help

Comment: Can you provide some examples of code so we can see what you're trying to achieve? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
 display : flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Keep this styling on your container box(parent box). This will place the inner div in the center and maintain the same when the height of the container is changed too.

Comment: We do not know what exactly the OP tries to achieve. The question is very broad. Giving a specific answer to a broad question that might not even solve this should be avoided. Besides of that, in that context the answer will most likely give an undesired result as so far he properly only talks about vertically centering.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
#container {
 display : flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

if this doesn't work
try to set certain width & height of box to be placed in middle  and follow according to parent container size.
For example: if the parent container measures 100% of width and width of box is 30% ; then give a

```
 margin-left : 35% ;
```

Similarly set the height and give margin-top.
Hope this method may help you out.
Sorry if this doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border:1px solid #DDD;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  background: #1695A3;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.box3 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
</div>
```